haproxy doesn't seem to see all the backends/replicas
I'm trying to make haproxy proxy requests to a number of replicas:
docker-compose.yml:
services:
  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:2.3-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    ports:
      - 8888:80
  app:
    build: .
    command: perl app.pl
    init: true
    deploy:
      replicas: 10

haproxy.cfg:
global
    maxconn  1024
listen in
    bind :80
    server-template srv 10 app:8080 check
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

But it seems to see only some of the replicas:
$ docker compose up
...
app-3      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
haproxy-1  | [NOTICE] 094/155107 (1) : New worker #1 (8) forked
app-4      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-2      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-5      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-9      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-7      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-6      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-1      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-10     | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-8      | MyWebServer: You can connect to your server at http://localhost:8080/
app-3      | d3757cd065b4
app-3      | d3757cd065b4
app-3      | d3757cd065b4
app-4      | 226419df4354
app-4      | 226419df4354
app-4      | 226419df4354
...

More details here.
What am I missing?

I'm unclear on the problem. You've configured 10 backend servers, and I see log output from 10 backends in your question. How are you determining that haproxy is unable to see some of these backends?

@larsks I'd expect it to use most if not all the backends even if the load is not big enough. Is this not how it works? Explaining how exactly it works and why it doesn't use all the backends is also an option. UPD I remember now. In production I see that only 2 out of 16 backends are used. And the load must be big enough. As such, I don't have a conclusive evidence, but the way it looks is like I said.

I'm not sure I understand the reason, but depends_on supposedly resolves the issue (haproxy depends on the apps). My guess is that haproxy caches what app resolves to when it starts. If not all the apps are running at that moment, it caches only the running IPs.
UPD depends_on is only part of the story, and it's likely not necessary if resolvers are used (run time (re)resolution). See these links:

Haproxy doesn’t resolve a domain to all the IPs
docker + haproxy
How to access docker-compose created replicas in haproxy config

